# Entity Framework 4 POCO's and AutoMapper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, poco, automapper

I have been working on a new MVC application that utilizies EF4, POCO Domain Objects and the Repository <--> Service Layer.

I see a lot of talk about using AutoMapper to map the EF4 classes to the DTO for the View Models. I was under the impression that this was to get rid of the tightly bound EF4 classes. So my question is since I am using the POCO classes, can't I just use those in the View Models? Or is there still a need for AutoMapper?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The argument is that your "POCO's" are your domain models, and your View's shouldn't be concerned with Domain Models.

Think about it this way - data validation, if you want data annotations, you would have to put them on your POCO's - but input validation (this field is required, etc) isn't really a domain concern, it's a UI concern - hence the use of ViewModels for Data Annotations and AutoMapper.

Of course, it's not cut and dry, it's a matter of preference.

I also use MVC/EF4/POCO/AutoMapper/Service Layer and i never bind to the POCO's - i always use a ViewModel per View.

This way, you have a good level of consistency:

- All View's have a ViewModel
- POCO's have nothing but business/domain logic
- ViewModel's have basic input validation
- They are then mapped to the POCO's, which invoke domain/business validation

**Edit - in response to comments: **

> Do your Repositories return IQueryable? If so, how do you handle the context? I mean does your Repositories implement IDisposable and then you dispose of them in the controllers?

Yes - my Repositories return `IQueryable<T>`, where T is an aggregate root. My Repositories get passed a Unit of Work (which implements IDisposable). The Unit of Work is a wrapper for the EF4 context. StructureMap (DI container) is responsible for the lifetime of the components (including the UoW - aka the context). I new up a UoW per HTTP request and Dispose when it's finished. My "Service" calls methods on my IQueryable repository and returns collections (e.g materializes the query before being passed back to the Controller).

> Where do you do your mapping at? Do you do it in the controller?

Up to you. Personally, i would create a static "bootstrapper" class that has a single method, e.g "Configure". Call this once in your Application_Start event (Global.asax). This technique is decribed [here](http://mhinze.com/2009/07/06/automapper-in-nerddinner/).

Good luck!

Comment: @RPM1984 - Thanks for the explanation? I have a couple other q's for you. 1) Do your Repositories return IQueryable? 2) If so, how do you handle the context? I mean does your Repositories implement IDisposable and then you dispose of them in the controllers? Thanks for all of your help!!

Comment: @RPM1984 - Where do you do your mapping at? Do you do it in the controller?

Comment: This response is a great example on why StackOverflow is the best site for good explanations and answers. Needed the same info myself, Thanks RPM1984! :)

Comment: @Yngve B Nilsen - glad i could help! :)

Comment: @RPM1984 - Thanks for the edit!! Do you happen to have any examples you are using in your framework. I mean sample code for the way you use the Repository/Service/EF/POCO/AutoMapper/DI technique?

Comment: @Sam Striano - i was afraid you'd ask that. :) There is a **lot** of code involved in that. May i suggest you look at some of my previous questions i've asked on Stack (when i was first setting up Repo/Service/POCO/DI), or have a google around. Don't mean to be lazy, it's just that i've asked/answered how to do that at least 3 or 4 times, and am getting bored of writing that code. :)

Comment: This is a really good implementation of EF4/POCO/Repository/UoW: http://elegantcode.com/2009/12/15/entity-framework-ef4-generic-repository-and-unit-of-work-prototype/. The only changes you need is put a service layer in the middle, and apply DI. But the hardest part is wiring up the repo/uow with the EF ctx.

Comment: Your example was such a gr8 help, I was looking for this !

Comment: @RPM1984 Do you use explicit relationship loading with EF and if you do where do you make your LoadProperty calls? I managed to configure AutoMapper to pre-load some relationships using BeforeMap but now I am worried if this is a good idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933519/automapper-and-entity-framework-poco-with-explicit-loading

Comment: @see me no more - i dont follow. What do you mean "explicit relationship loading"? Do you mean "eager loading"? If so, i do this in the Repository. I pass in a few `bool` flags, e.g `bool loadPosts`, then check that and do `.Include` accordingly.

Comment: @RPM1984 explicit loading as described here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx. I think I made a mistake of making my repositories too generic and now I end up doing more work in service layer. Having more flexible repository methods like you describe may actually solve my problems. Then AutoMapper will deal with fully loaded entity graph.